# Query on getting the variables of production rates of microphysical processes in WRF output

Tags: model, weather

I am using the Morrison double-moment microphysics scheme while running WRF version 3.9.1. I know that one can include the variables in the WRF model output files by making an iofields file (say,'my_iofields_list.txt') and setting the following line in the 'time_control' section of the namelist.input:
iofields_filename = 'my_iofields_list.txt','my_iofields_list.txt',

So, can anyone please tell me the variables related to production or conversion rates of microphysical processes (units are either in gg-1s-1 or kgm-2h-1, as per the literature) so that I can add in the final wrfout_d0* files?
Can anyone please guide me on these? That will be very helpful for me. Thank you for your time and consideration.
With regards,
Ankan